# What happens to Tyrell in the woods?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

At the end of Mr.Robot S4E4,

> Tyrell Wellick is shot and walks off into the woods where he follows a screeching sound to find a glowing light. His actual death...

...is never shown and he is never seen again for the rest of the series including the finale.

What happened to him?

Has there been anything (eg. interviews, blogs, etc) from the show insiders like the writers as to what actually happened (even them explicitly saying it was written to be vague)? Any known *out-of-universe* explanations from insiders, eg. actor scheduling issues, etc?

---

A possibly related aside (and would need to watch the episode again to double check), but

> when Whiterose's machine is activated/running/exploding during either the final or semi-final episode, that same sound as when Tyrell finds the pulsing light can be heard briefly (possibly just show reusing sound effects).

(Will try to watch again and add timestamp when can).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tyrell is dead, he died alone in the woods.

[This article from the Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/mr-robot-final-season-tyrell-wellicks-fate-explained-1250083) features quotes from both Sam Esmail and Martin Wallström explaining their thoughts on it.  I've added a short excerpt below but the whole article is a bit too long to quote.

> Moments after the epiphany, Elliot and Tyrell come across the Dark
>   Army operative, who kills himself, but not before fatally shooting
>   Tyrell. Recognizing his own impending demise and the ramifications of
>   what happens if his body is discovered by the Dark Army, Tyrell
>   chooses to walk back into the woods to die alone, buying Elliot some
>   time in his quest against Whiterose (BD Wong). The episode ends with
>   Tyrell stumbling toward a glowing blue light, before the scene fades
>   to white.
>
> From the outside looking in, Tyrell's death comes as a shock on a few
>   different levels. For one, it's only a quarter of the way into the
>   final season; Tyrell has been a central figure in the Mr. Robot mythos
>   from the very beginning, even earning the iconic penultimate line of
>   the pilot: "Bonsoir, Elliot." For another, Tyrell dies just as he was
>   about to be named the new CEO of E Corp — literally, dying one day
>   short of the coveted appointment. But **as Esmail explains to THR,**
>   **Tyrell's inopportune demise** was right for the same reason he felt it
>   necessary to kill off Angela: "The story told us when it was time."

Comment: For others: this quote from Wallström in the linked article is also directly relevant to the question: "It wasn't clear to me what that was. Sam and I talked about it, but in my mind, ***we* weren't sure if it's something that only we see, or if it's something that's in his head**. When I thought about it, it was so much about coming to peace with everything finally working out."